# Setting up PhoneGap 1.8.1 and Sencha Touch 2 project. Cant call Ext.setup

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch

with help of the Eclipse Plugin MDS 1.1 for PhoneGap on Android i was setting up a new project including Sencha Touch.

Target Android 4.0.3
min SDK 15

Problem is that when i want to call Ext.setup that the function doesnt Exist.
I ve included the sencha-touch.js files in the index.html and the css as well.

Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may have setup your Sencha project incorrectly at creation.  MY recommendation would be to use the Sencha SDK tools to create a new blank project, using this command line:

```
sencha generate app <name> <location>
```

Check this page for more info - [Sencha Getting Started](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/getting_started)

If you want to try to fix your current page without recreating, you could use the created one as a sample.  Just offhand I know that in your index.html you want to load the microloader script, as opposed to the js libraries themselves.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i figured it out. somehow it didnt work with sencha-touch-debug.js... just got a blank screen. Instead of debug i used sencha-touch-all.js and now the deviceready as well as the launch function of ST2 fire.